# Selenium Python - get chrome console messages

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is there any way to get chrome console messages(when you press F12 - and all messages in the console tab - [The console tab in with the blue line under it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEA7Q.png)  ) using Selenium? I need to search and copy some data from it so I need to copy it for a list or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this should help:

```
for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
    print(entry)
```